# How to get all the members of a group in chef?

Tags: chef-infra, ohai-gem

Is there a more-elegant method for getting users (in a given group) in chef than iterating over etc/passwd? I suppose I could use search functionality to get the list of group members from data bags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [ohai](http://docs.opscode.com/ohai.html) gives you such information. You can access these [automatic attributes](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files_attribute_automatic.html) like any other attribute.

You find information about the groups in `node[:etc][:group]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the group members using `getent`

```
def get_local_users_within_gid(gid)
  # return list of users
  shell_out!("getent group #{gid}").stdout.strip().split(':').last.split(',')
end
```